# CMD Using EnableDelayedExpansion with spliting string

Tags: loops, for-loop, cmd, split

Sorry for my wording first off didn't know how to phrase this. My question is I have a loop with 2 variable and I want to simply check if a number of characters exist example code of this is:

```
if %time:~8,1% EQU "" echo Less than 8 characters
```

My code in my head (which is wrong) looks like this

```
set "AN1=Little String"
set "AN2=Along String More Character"
set "AN3=Extra String With A Lot Character"
set "AN3=SmallSt"
for /l %%A IN (1,1,28) DO (
    If Not !AN%%!:~8,1 EQU "" (echo String has Less than 8 characters) ELSE (
    If Not !AN%%!:~16,1 EQU "" (echo String has Less than 16 characters) ELSE (
    If Not !AN%%!:~24,1 EQU "" (echo String has Less than 24 characters) ELSE (
    )
)
```

Comment: do you want to compute the length of something contained in a variable?

Comment: I'm adding indents for appearance purposes. If I find if a char for exists in the 8 slot I subtract an indent and it lines up finding the exact number of characters would help but it might be over kill for my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to test an "array" of strings against length thresholds. You logic is inverted (if 8th char is not empty then string is shorter than 8: wrong) apart from that it's close.

The key is this: `set V=!AN%%A%!`. That allows to "generate" a variable name from another one. The `EnableDelayedExpansion` part is useful to be able to use another separator than `%`: `!` otherwise the nesting would fail.

I've taken an example with 5 strings to cover all the tests.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "AN1=Little String"
set "AN2=Along String More Character"
set "AN3=Extra String With A Lot Character"
set "AN4=SmallSt"
set "AN5=Along String More "

for /l %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (

    set V=!AN%%A%!

    If "!V:~8,1!"=="" (echo "!V!" String has Less than 8 characters) else (
    If "!V:~16,1!"=="" (echo "!V!" String has Less than 16 characters) else (
    If "!V:~24,1!"=="" (echo "!V!" String has Less than 24 characters)
  )
   )
)
```

Result:

```
"Little String" String has Less than 16 characters
"SmallSt" String has Less than 8 characters
"Along String More " String has Less than 24 characters
```